# Не могу создать больше 47 одновременно работающих ofstream потоков

Tags: c++, c++builder

В общем вот пример в среде rad studio xe7:

```
...
ofstream *test[60];
String t;
for(int i=1;i<=46;i++)
{
   t="test"+String(i)+".log";
   test[i]=new ofstream(t.c_str(),std::ios_base::trunc);
   (*test[i])<<"текст"<<i<<std::endl;
} 
ofstream test1;
test1.open("test47.log",std::ios_base::trunc);

ofstream test2;
test2.open("testNotWork.log",std::ios_base::trunc);
Form1->Memo1->Text=strerror(test2.rdstate());
...
```

Первые 47 потоков создаются и работают хорошо, последующие просто не создаются.

Comment: Даже в древнем BCB6 можно открыть тысячи файлов таким образом (проверил на Win7Pro). Может быть у Вас на модификацию `testNotWork.log` прав нет?

Answer (score 1):

В системе всегда есть ограничение на количество открытых файлов.

Увы, в каждой системе решение по увеличению ограничения свое.

Comment: 47 что-то не тянет на системное ограничение, не? Ну +3 стандартных - получается 50. Явно не программистское число, зато кругленькое...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел `TFileStream`, открывает сколько нужно.